# is there any way to use forEach in where condition in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, lambda

I have a Dictionary Like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> schedule { get; set; }
```

That the keys are the days (sat,sun,...) and the values are the list of times ("10-12","12-14",...)

So I tried to query in database for fetch teachers that present in these times, for reach that I write this query:

```
// Post: api/Schedules/teachers
[HttpPost("teachers")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>> GetTeachersSchedule([FromForm] TS request)
{
    return await _context.teachers
        .Join(_context.images.Where(i => i.imageable_type == "Teacher"), l => l.id, i => i.imageable_id, (l, i) => new { teachers = l, image = i })
        .Join(_context.schedule_teachers, q => q.teachers.id, p => p.teacher_id, (q, p) => new { teachers = q, schedule_teacher = p })
        .Join(_context.schedules, q => q.schedule_teacher.schedule_id, p => p.id, (q, p) => new { teachers = q, schedules = p })


        //.Where( q =>
        //foreach (List<string> times in request.schedule)
        //    q.schedules.day == "FOO"
        //)




        .Select(q => new
        {
            image = Path.Combine("/Images/md/", q.teachers.teachers.image.name),
            q.teachers.teachers.teachers.id,
            q.teachers.teachers.teachers.first_name,
            q.teachers.teachers.teachers.last_name,
            q.teachers.teachers.teachers.license_type,
            q.teachers.teachers.teachers.description,
        })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

I know this query has syntax error but how can I implement this query in correct way.

sorry for ask this bad question but I'm newer in asp.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are trying to retrieve from the database, the model of teachers would be appreciated to help you solve the problem. And why are you doing the joins

Comment: You can use `.Any()` inside your `.Where()`, like this `.Where(q => q.schedules.Any(schedule => schedule.day == "FOO"))`, but it's hard to write a complete answer without knowing your domain. Add more info to your post, like your `DbContext` and the classes involved in the joins.

Comment: Need the model for `schedule_teachers` to answer this